# Proximal mapping and projection

Tags: projection, simplex

Show that for $x = [x_1; x_2; \ldots; x_n]$,
$$
\max_{1 \le i \le n} \{x_i\} = \max_{y \in C} \{x*y\},
$$
where $C$ is the unit simplex defined by $$C = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n| y > 0, 1^Ty = 1\}.$$
Hence, prove that the proximal mapping of $f : \Bbb R^n → \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x) =
\max_{1≤i≤n}\{x_i\}$ is given by
$$
P_f (x) = x − Π_C(x)
$$
where $Π_C(x)$ is the projection of $x$ onto $C$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would be nice. I tried to get you started.

Comment: Also, please update the question with your own work/thoughts/progress so it would be easier to guide you. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: What do you mean by $xy$ and $1y = 1$? Am I wrong in thinking that, in each case, $x, y \in \Bbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @user754697 quite likely, each of those denotes the dot product, but I agree it is very confusing

Comment: @gt6989b It was my first thought. On the other hand, I can cite papers on projections where $xy$ refers to the distance $\|x - y\|$. It's also not clear what $y1$ means, given $1$ is typically a scalar. Does it refer to a vector of $1$s? Then the $1$ on the left and on the right must be different. It's just too much to assume; we really need clarification.

Comment: @user754697 Agree, I thought $y1$ is really $\vec{y} \cdot \vec{1}$, so the sum of all components of $y$. But let the OP clarify